# Is there a way to hide Maven 2 "target/" folder in Eclipse 3?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2

I'm using maven 2.0.9 with Eclipse 3.3.2.

I'm used to launching a fresh build once per day by a `mvn clean install`.
Then, if I refresh my Eclipse project, it will be "polluted" by files from Maven's *target* directory.

That's very annoying while performing searches, getting resources by "open resource" and so on.

Is there a way to avoid Eclipse looking in this folder?

Answer (score 58):

Right click on the folder you want to ignore, open the "Properties" dialog, chose the "Resource" tab and check the box that says "Derived"

Comment: The only problem with this method is that if you ever call maven eclipse:clean, you have to reapply your project changes.  =/

Comment: Right-click on the folder, then select PROPERTIES, then check "Derived".  At least, that's what you have to do with Galileo.

Comment: If it doesn't seem to work, make sure you delete all history items in  the Open Resource Dialog...

Comment: @paulgreg : you need to mark this answer as accepted, please.
confirmed to work on Eclipse Helios 3.6 SR2

Comment: This _doesn't_ seem to work for me, however I'm not sure what or where the "Open Resource Dialog" is. I've tried cleaning the project, but I'm still getting a warning about a unnecessary cast...

Comment: In eclipse neon it appears that even running a "mvn clean compile" (which recreates the target folder) preserves the 'derived' option.

Answer (score 25):

Reconfigure "clean" in Maven not to delete target directory:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
        <filesets>
            <!-- delete directories that will be generated when you 
                 start the develpment server/client in eclipse  
            -->
            <fileset>
                <directory>target</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </fileset>
        </filesets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

(found at: http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/how-to-NOT-delete-target-dir-td3389739.html#a3413930)

Comment: This completes Zack's answer (most voted). Without this workaround, that solution is useless.
Works great. Unfortunately, it has to be set for every project.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's just what I needed! Having to set "derived" flag after each clean was really frustrating.

Comment: Thank you. Actually this should be the accepted answer, as it addresses the real problem of the questioner. It should be noted though, that excludeDefaultDirectories is only available since 2.3 of the maven-clean-plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/clean-mojo.html

Answer (score 18):

Solution for Indigo [SR2]

`Project Explorer` > `Customize View` > `Filters` > `[*] Maven Build Folder`

Answer (score 10):

I have been so pissed by this problem that I wrote a plugin to solve it. You get get the source and jar from:

https://github.com/YA2O/Eclipse_Plugin_Target_Derivator

Comment: Your pluging works great.I just dropped https://github.com/YA2O/Eclipse_Plugin_Target_Derivator/tree/master/plugins it into eclipse/dropins/ folder and had to modify *.jar/icons/Pointy.gif to some smaller one otherwise it makes toolbar height too big.

Answer (score 4):

To solve this problem here is what I did:

Install Groovy Monkey for Eclipse

Created a Bean Shell Script "UpdateMavenDerived_Beanshell.gm" to mark any directory named target as derived.

-----------Cut below here for script--------------

```
/*
 * Menu: Find System Prints > Beanshell
 * Script-Path: /GroovyMonkeyScripts/monkey/UpdateMavenDerived_Beanshell.gm
 * Kudos: Bjorn Freeman-Benson & Ward Cunningham & James E. Ervin
 * License: EPL 1.0
 * LANG: Beanshell
 * DOM: http://groovy-monkey.sourceforge.net/update/plugins/net.sf.groovyMonkey.dom
 */
out.println("Setting target directories to derived status.");
var projects = workspace.getRoot().getProjects();
for ( var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
    var project = projects[i];
    if (project.isOpen()) {
        out.println("Project: " + project.getName());
        var members = project.members();
        for ( var j = 0; j < members.length; j++) {
            if (members[j].getName().equals("target")) {
                out.println("setting derived status on: "+ members[j].getFullPath());
                members[j].setDerived(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is more complicated than id needs to be ;) but still decent

Answer (score 3):

Did you try configuring the "Java Element Filters" option dialog box, (through the top-right arrow of the project explorer) ?

If needed, you can define your own [ViewerFilter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsphelp/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_jdt_ui_javaElementFilters.html)

Comment: I tried that several weeks ago but wasn't able to get what I want.

Answer (score 3):

Preferences > Team > Ignored Resources

Add "target", and restart Eclipse.

Comment: This only tells your version control to ignore it. No apparent affect on any other operations.

Comment: Removes it from team synchronise view, which the others do not. at least not for me anyway.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me, running Kepler.

Comment: The issue with this is that it ignores any directory called "target" anywhere. Which means that any sources under org/msytuff/target are ignored. Ok, maybe you shouldn't call things like this, but as I work with other people's code, I can't take the chance...

Answer (score 2):

The maven plugin does not hide away the target directory. It does however use the maven target folders to configure eclipse. So target/classes and target/test-classes are used by eclipse, and eclipse filters these folders out. This is done by "mvn eclipse:eclipse" as well as by the m2eclipse plugin. What is left visible is everything in the target directory besides these two folders (the generated jar file for example).

You can create a filter for the package explorer, but that will not influence the "open resource".

Answer (score 2):

I had some issues because some solutions here only work for some views, so I made an illustrated summary.

<sub>Tested in Eclipse 4.4 (Luna), should work like this since 3.7 according to other answers here.</sub>

## Package Explorer

*Package Explorer View Menu* → `Filters...` →  check `Name filter patterns` and input `target`.

Be careful, this will hide all folders and files named `target`, not just the default maven build directory! The *Project Explorer* view has a better option without this issue.

[image: Package Explorer Menu]
[image: Package Explorer Dialog]

## Project Explorer

Project Explorer View Menu → `Custom View...` →  search for "maven" and check `Maven build folder`.

Checking this option hides the build directory as defined in the projects pom.xml configuration.

[image: Project Explorer Menu]
[image: Project Explorer Dialog]

Comment: Unfortunately this does not remove it from the open resource (ctrl+shift+r) or open type(ctrl+shift+t) menus which makes keyboard navigation still difficult but it does work perfectly for the package explorer view

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Maven plugin for Eclipse?

I would imagine it would hide some of the 'pollution' for you.

It would also allow you to perform the build within Eclipse - meaning it would refresh the project view for you at the same time.

[Maven 2 Eclipse](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html)

Comment: No, I'm not using currently the maven plugin for eclipse but I'll try that.

Comment: I am using it, but it doesn't hide the target folder stuff. The "Derived" technique works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using Resource filter looks solve issue if you using 'mvn clean install' frequently.

Basically it will add 'target' to and sub folders to exclude folder directly to .project file. After run this script, if you import project to eclipse, you can see the setting 'Project'->'Properties'->'Resource'->'Resource Filters'.  Before this whenever I run mvn clean install, eclipse took 50% of my CPU but now it stay under 5% while build project.

---

```
function eclipse-setup() {
     mvn eclipse:clean
     mvn eclipse:eclipse
     #maven target folders
     find . -name .project -exec sed -i.MSORG 's/<\/projectDescription>/<filteredResources> <filter> <id>1314376338264<\/id> <name><\/name> <type>26
<\/type> <matcher> <id>org.eclipse.ui.ide.multiFilter<\/id> <arguments>1.0-name-matches-false-false-target<\/arguments> <\/matcher> <\/filter> <filt
er> <id>1314387234341<\/id> <name><\/name> <type>6<\/type> <matcher> <id>org.eclipse.ui.ide.multiFilter<\/id> <arguments>1.0-name-matches-false-fals
e-*.cache.html<\/arguments> <\/matcher> <\/filter> <\/filteredResources><\/projectDescription>/' {} \;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When Eclipse freezes, looking at the process activity, I can see it browsing all my target, .hg and .git directories. Moreover, those directories are also copied into Eclipse's bin directory. A lot of CPU and disk usage for nothing.

Not cleaning the target directory is not an acceptable solution.

There was a solution using a Monkey script (http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Eclipse-amp-target-directory-td72354.html) but the project has been closed.

I still look for a solution to tell Eclipse to ignore Maven target directories, as well as .hg and .git directories.

Eclipse continuously watching those is a pain.

I also use m2eclipse but it doesn't solve that issue.

Comment: Try KeepTargetDerivedPlugin plugin:
 http://sourceforge.net/projects/etinyplugins/files/KeepTargetDerivedPlugin/