# How to ignore XML warnings from a specific folder in Eclipse?

Tags: java, maven, warnings, m2eclipse

I'm building a java project with Eclipse and the plugin m2e (it adds Maven support in Eclipse).

There some XML Surefire reports ine the `target` directory. They generate annoying warnings because they have neither a DTD nor an XML Schema.

How can you tell Eclipse to ignore `**/target` folders ?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757507/how-can-i-stop-eclipse-warning-about-target-folders-contents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the following image:
Open the preferences `Window > Preferences`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The whole `target/` folder can be excluded from Eclipse's "management" by marking it as `derived`. Right-click on the `target/` folder and go to properties:

[image]

This disables validation, excludes this directory from search, "Open Resource" lookup, etc. Unfortunately, you'll have to remember to toggle it after every project Build since it switches back to "off" by default.

Answer (score 1):

1. open the Preferences (Windoww > Preferences)
2. go to xml validation XML > XML Files > Validation
3. set "No grammar specified" to Ignore

Edit: I see you want it for a specific folder... but I'm afraid this only works on workspace or at least project level